# Dropbox disappearing from system tray after unplugging from second monitor

Tags: kubuntu, multiple-monitors, dropbox, system-tray

I am running kubuntu 14.04. Dropbox works fine, and there the icon (with sync status) appears in the system tray.

I have a second monitor, which also has a kde panel on it (no system tray in this panel). When I plug the second monitor in everything is still fine. Once I unplug the second monitor the system tray icon disapears. Running

```
dropbox status
```

shows that it is still running, and things sync fine. But I now have no icon which bugs me. If I restart dropbox the icon comes back, but this is annoying has there are 200GB of files it needs to check, so it takes a long time be ready again.

Also as some extra info, dropbox is never listed in the entries tab of the system tray settings, whether or not the icon is displaying.

Any idea how to stop it disappearing, or just a command to get it to reappear that doesn't fully restart dropbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems that this is a similar issue to a question asked a month later for Xubuntu ([Dropbox icon is not working Xubuntu 14.04 LTS 64](https://askubuntu.com/questions/732967/dropbox-icon-is-not-working-xubuntu-14-04-lts-64)). The issue relates to dbus sessions in a way I don't understand. But I can fix the issue by running:

```
dropbox stop && DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="" dropbox start
```