# How to fix non working Dropbox icon on Xubuntu 14.04 LTS 64?

Tags: xubuntu, icons, dropbox, xfce-panel

A few hours ago the dropbox icon in Xubuntu 14.04 stopped working.
The icon is black with a red slashed zero. I cannot click on it to bring up the dropbox menu. I believe there was an update right before this happened. 
I reinstalled then purged dropbox. I even deleted all associated files and hidden folders and after I installed it again. Still, the icon is not working. Tried to stop and start the service... again nothing.

Comment: You can always downgrade Dropbox. I am on 3.12.5 and have no icon issues. I hope Dropbox will not auto-update it soon. However, there is a way to block this also. http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=184839&p=959212#p959212   https://dl-web.dropbox.com/u/17/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-3.12.5.tar.gz

Comment: I have reported this bug with all necessary details to Dropbox. I had a similar issue before with Linux Mint. They held off on upgrading my Dropbox until the version with a bug fix. I am a paid user, and they state that I should receive a response within 24-48 hours. If they reply with key information, I'll be sure to post here.

Comment: You may be able to downgrade without first uninstalling. This might avoid a complete re-index of all Dropbox files. It may fix the icon issue until the bug is fixed and then they push out that update.

Comment: How can we do that, @jbrock?

Comment: @mcwise At this page, https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx, follow the instructions for headless install. However, instead of using their link, use the link I have posted above to the tar.gz file. This should overwrite your install with version 3.12.5. Dropbox seems to be waiting and not upgrading that version yet.

Comment: This bug was reported on Launchpad meanwhile: https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1546176 (Also, this question is linked in one of the comments :-)

Comment: This bug re-appears on Ubuntu 17.10 and none of below work

Comment: @ScottStensland the sudo option worked for me however it creates a permissions nightmare so I absolutely wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: This bug also goes for Ubuntu...

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Just got this bug on my Xubuntu 15.10, broken icon and no way to open the menu. I think the bug is connected to Dropbox starting to use "indicator area" for their tray icon instead of "notification area" and the sudo-fix just happens to work because of some environment variables are not in use with sudo sessions.

At least for me this problem can be fixed by running:

```
dropbox stop && DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="" dropbox start
```

This seems to move the icon back to "notification area" which fixes both icon and menu. This way the daemon runs as a normal user and not as root.

EDIT: If you create your own startup script for Dropbox based on this fix, remember to disable the default startup script with "`dropbox autostart n`" command (Thank StockBreak for this one, saved me some time this morning).

EDIT2: ...and for some reason I still had to remove the autostart setting from Dropbox GUI (click icon >> Preferences >> Start Dropbox on system startup). Hope it stays off after this one.

EDIT: To implement this fix in a script that run every time session starts, try this solution: https://askubuntu.com/a/795864/496493

Comment: This kk78's workaround also works for me, giving the tray icon for normal user. I've not tried StockBreak's desktop entry for this but probably works as well. Instead, I'm using the #!/bin/bash line and kk78's line as a simple shell script in a "dropboxicon.sh" text file with the executable property, and right click > Actions > Run In Konsole, until the bug is fixed. This workaround works well. Thank you.

Comment: Xubuntu 14.04 64bit LTS - confirmed same exact problem, confirmed above work-a-round does the trick (all be it temporarily).

Comment: Had the same problem in Kubuntu 14.04 and also here it solved the issue!

Comment: Worked also for 16.04 eventually, but I had to install and add another `indicator-applet` to the panel (aside to the already available and present `indicator-applet-complete`), otherwise the dropbox icon simply didn't appear. This on a new installation of Ubuntu 16.04 x86 (on a very old Toshiba laptop), running a `gnome-fallback` session with `metacity`.

Comment: For some reason even removing the autostart setting from Dropbox GUI did not stop dropbox from autostarting, but I guess that is why there is `dropbox stop` in the script.

Comment: Great... now I'm getting `Unable to monitor entire Dropbox folder hierarchy. Please run "echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=100000 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf; sudo sysctl -p" and restart Dropbox to fix the problem.`

Comment: `dropbox stop && DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="" dropbox start` not work in Ubuntu 17.04. 
**After running the command, it appears but with broken icon and without menu.**

Comment: On 17.04 you might try the "new workaround" below i.e. `dropbox stop && dbus-launch dropbox start`. I've been using it on my laptop (currently Xubuntu 17.04) and haven't had problems. It would be really nice if Dropbox fixed this...

Answer (score 83):

A **new workaround**, proposed by [File C.](https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/204590143-Tray-icon-not-responding-linux-mint-17-3#community_comment_206851426), is *"dbus-launch dropbox start -i"*.

The following adaptations are reported by users to work at least on the Linux distributions Fedora, Gentoo, Kubuntu, Linux Mint, openSUSE, Slackware, Ubuntu, Xubuntu... and the desktop environments Cinnamon, KDE 4, KDE 5, Mate, Unity, Xfce...

This new *dbus-launch* workaround seems to work a little faster, with more reliability, and in more cases than the previous *DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS* workaround.

As command line:

```
dropbox stop && dbus-launch dropbox start
```

Or as a shell script file:

```
#!/bin/bash

dropbox stop && dbus-launch dropbox start
```

Comment: The command line command works great but only works for that session. To make the fix permanent, one should, after running this command, go to the Dropbox indicator > Preferences... > uncheck Start Dropbox on system startup. Then add `dbus-launch dropbox start` to Session and Startup > Application Autostart. This works perfectly for me on Xubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: This was the only way for me to get it to work in Ubuntu Mint xenial 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Annoyingly I can't edit my comment. The application autostart command perhaps should be `dbus-launch dropbox start -i` (this works on Ubuntu (GNOME) Flashback 16.10, idk whether it works on Xubuntu as well)

Comment: This works in lubuntu 16.4

Comment: @Ads20000 this didn't work on Kubuntu 14.04 because KDE restores your session when you login. The dbus-launch fails since dropbox is already running. Rather that prepend a `dropbox stop` to the command, I entered `dropbox` in System Settings->Startup and Shutdown->Session Management->Applications to be excluded from sessions.

Comment: The `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=""` solution did nothing for me, but this one worked! Running Linux Mint 17.3.

Comment: This solution worked for me on Linux Mint 18, Cinammon 3.0

Comment: This workaround is working well for example for a laptop with Linux Mint 17.2 (based on Ubuntu 14.04) and KDE 4.13.2. However, not sure why, but for a more recent Linux version the bug seems somehow fixed with no more need for workaround: this happens on another laptop with Linux Mint 18 (based on Ubuntu 16.04) and KDE Plasma 5.6.5.  Maybe this particular fix is in the KDE version, since Linux Mint 18 still has the bug for other users, and Dropbox doesn't seem to have made a general fix yet.

Comment: It seems that after a fresh update of today, this workaround is no longer working for me. Does anybody have any suggestions? I am on Xubuntu 16.04.1

Comment: I can confirm this workaround helps with Dropbox not displaying tray icon in Cinnamon 3.2.7. [Currently running Fedora 25, Cinnamon spin.] Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: This is the only solution that works on Ubuntu 16.10 (yakkety).  Thanks!

Comment: The original worked for me, may have to try some of the permanent solutions like the script etc. But for now, happy to see the dropbox icon working well. I'm running Mint Xfce 18.1 64 bit

Comment: Works on Budgie 17.04 :)

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 14.04 Mate.

Comment: Can anyone explain why this works?

Comment: Doesn't work for me on Ubuntu 21.10.

Answer (score 21):

Thanks to kk78's solution I made this complete workaround (see also my [other post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/732894/dropbox-icon-corrupted-on-xubuntu-15-10/736336#736336)):

I **copied*** my desktop entry:

```
cp ~/.config/autostart/dropbox.desktop ~/.config/autostart/start_dropbox.desktop
```

Changed the entry like this (please notice the `env` word):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Dropbox
GenericName=File Synchronizer
Comment=Sync your files across computers and to the web
#Exec=dropbox start -i
Exec=env DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="" dropbox start -i
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=dropbox
Categories=Network;FileTransfer;
StartupNotify=false
```

And disabled Dropbox's autostart:

```
dropbox autostart n
```

* you cannot just edit it because Dropbox replaces the file every time you log in.

Comment: This did it for me, though for clarification: you edit the start_dropbox.desktop file (with mousepad or whatever)

Comment: another note: in menulibre (or your menu system) you need to change the command entry from "dropbox start -i" to "env DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="" dropbox start -i" so the right one runs when initiated from the menu.

Answer (score 8):

*[This is my deprecated early answer, now kept to research this and related bugs; for newer and better workarounds, without the file ownership change/recovery inconvenience of sudo, see kk78's answer instead, or the command line `"dropbox stop && dbus-launch dropbox start"` in another answer]*

This Dropbox tray icon bug seems to be related to permissions.

Until it gets fixed, a temporary workaround from the command line (Konsole, Terminal, etc.), which is working these days for users of Xubuntu, Linux Mint, etc.:

```
dropbox stop
sudo dropbox start
```

**Note:**

About the *"sudo"*, running Dropbox as root overcomes the permission bug, and the tray icon works again correctly.

However, it has the small secondary effect of having a few files in the hidden folder *~/.dropbox/* owned by root now instead of the user (as you can see with e.g. a file manager such as Dolphin), and therefore the root password is requested when starting Dropbox.

This is ok as a temporary workaround to get the Dropbox tray icon fully working on Linux until the bug is hopefully fixed by a next update, but if the fix doesn't restore the correct permissions, in that hypothetical case a quick solution after the bug fix will be:

```
sudo dropbox stop
sudo chown -R USER:GROUP /home/USER/.dropbox
dropbox start
```

Of course, replacing USER and GROUP. For example, if you are co-creator of Unix, UTF-8, Go language, etc. ;) it would be something like:

```
sudo chown -R ken:ken /home/ken/.dropbox
```

**Update:**

Sorry, I've just seen something that makes this temporary workaround still workable but less convenient: Not only those few already mentioned files in the hidden *~/.dropbox* folder get owned by root, also the files downloaded from the Dropbox servers to the Dropbox folder (usually *~/Dropbox*) on the computer running Dropbox as root.

So, I'm still using this workaround until the bug fix, but if we want to use it we have to apply the permissions recovery line also to the Dropbox folder, at least when we want to edit our downloaded documents. For example:

```
sudo chown -R USER:GROUP /home/USER/Dropbox
```

To save time, and to apply it when we start the computer, we can include it in a simple shell script, e.g. a *dropbox.sh* text file with the executable property, that we can run from the command line or by mouse click:

```
#!/bin/bash

dropbox stop
sudo dropbox start
sudo chown -R USER:GROUP /home/USER/Dropbox
```

**Simple alternative workaround:**

Instead of all the previous procedures, if dealing with file ownership changes and recoveries, etc. is too inconvenient, the simplest alternative is probably to just wait for the Dropbox bug fix without using the icon, and simply check the Dropbox status from time to time using the command line:

```
dropbox status
```

The result, if Dropbox is running, most of the time will be: *"Up to date"*.

Later, probably you can use the up arrow to quickly run this line again from a small command line window that you can keep open.

See additional command line help by just typing:

```
dropbox
```

As already suggested, to stop using the other workaround (sudo), recover normal file ownership, and start running Dropbox again as normal user instead of root, use just one time (replacing USER and GROUP):

```
sudo dropbox stop
sudo chown -R USER:GROUP /home/USER/Dropbox
sudo chown -R USER:GROUP /home/USER/.dropbox
sudo chown -R USER:GROUP /home/USER/.dbus
dropbox start
```

**New update:**

See **kk78's answer** to this question, with a much better workaround than mine, and with Dropbox tray icon as normal user, not root. It works at least for Xubuntu and Linux Mint.

It can also be used as a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

dropbox stop && DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="" dropbox start
```

Comment: This workaround DOES work in my Xubuntu 14.04 64. Everybody please notice the "sudo". Thank you Juan M. Gonzalez

Comment: However we have to remember that my suggestion of running as root just for these days is a really temporary workaround, and the real solution should come from a quick bug fix by Dropbox.

Comment: In practice, I'm finding that the simple "dropbox status" workaround without icon is better and more convenient than the other "sudo dropbox start" workaround with icon.

Comment: New: See kk78's answer, with a much better workaround than mine.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of staying on an older version or fiddling with other aspects, I have decided to use this script instead of the little icon. It puts the output from the command `dropbox status` directly in your panel. However, when it is syncing or up to date there is a little check mark or syncing character.

Install the Generic Monitor by pasting the following in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4-genmon-plugin
```

Set the following script to run using the Generic Monitor panel plugin. I went without a Label and set it to run every five seconds.

```
#!/bin/bash

status=$(dropbox status)
if [ "$status" = "Up to date" ]; then
    echo "✔"
elif [[ "$status" == "Syncing"* ]] || [[ "$status" == "Indexing"* ]]  || [[ "$status" == "Downloading"* ]]; then
    echo "⟲"
else
    echo "$status"
fi
```

You'll need to run the following so it does not show a password prompt (which can be disregarded anyways) on login:

```
sudo chown -R USER:GROUP ~/.dropbox
```

`USER:GROUP` is normally just your username twice.

When I need to change a setting I will just launch Dropbox with `sudo` to change my settings. As documented on this page launching with `sudo` enables the little icon and menu to appear.

Additionally you can echo out [your own Dropbox icon](http://goodies.xfce.org/projects/panel-plugins/xfce4-genmon-plugin) or image if you prefer that. If your Dropbox command line is not working, you can download the Dropbox python script [here](https://www.dropbox.com/help/9192). (In my case I am not using the *.py extension for the Dropbox python script name.)

Comment: Quite cool, never knew I could do this! Useful for lots of other things. Cheers.

Comment: Very cool!  Thanks for sharing this.  I didn't know about the Generic Monitor.

Comment: Why `bash -c` and not just `dropbox status`?

Comment: Do you still have the red icon displayed in panel?

Comment: @jarno I have a faint memory that initially it did not work by only putting `$(dropbox status)`. However, for some reason `$(bash -c 'dropbox status')` did work. Using `$(dropbox status)` now works so I've updated my script accordingly. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @jarno I do not use the Notification Area or the Indicator plugin. So, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3):

I modified the `~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd` script as follows and rebooted and got the icon back.   Since this file gets overwritten by updates I think I won't have to undo anything if they fix the problem on the next update.

```
#!/bin/sh
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=""
PAR=$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")")
exec "$PAR/dropbox-lnx.x86-3.14.7/dropboxd" "$@"
```

Update: When I tried this on my laptop it didn't work at first.  I realized I was having the same problem I had with 'Copy' where the XFCE4 session saving was starting dropbox before the official startup file was executed.
I modified my ~/.profile file to erase any *.state  and *session* files in `~./cache/sessions`

```
rm -f /home/jhm/.cache/sessions/*.state
rm -f /home/jhm/.cache/sessions/*session*
```

Update #2:  So now using version 3.18.1 the problem is still there. I know because , as I predicted, the `~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd` script was overwritten with every update causing the problem to return each time. The fix above works reliably on Xubuntu 14.04 boot provided session restoring does not directly launch the binary:

`/home/<user>/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86-3.18.1/dropbox`

Using "System/Session and Startup", under the "Session" tab I can see that the binary is visible and would be restarted if I didn't delete the *session and *state files.

As an experiment, I tried using Upstart to launch Dropbox before session tracking started.
First I created the `/home/jhm/.init` folder, then a file called `dropbox.conf` was added to it containing:

```
description "Dropbox"
start on desktop-start
expect daemon
exec /usr/bin/dropbox start
```

I use this method on my Dell Laptop Xubuntu 14.04, and the program is now hidden from session tracking, so I don't need to delete files.

Since `dbus-launch` creates a new private DBUS session bus,  DropBox will never find the appindicator service as it will be the only process on that bus (other than DBUS), so thats about the same as `export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=""` Both solutions cause DropBox to fallback to the system tray API.  This is called a 'Notification Area' in XFCE Panel Items tab. Be sure it hasn't been removed from the panel.

Using `d-feet` and `dbus-monitor`, I found the problem was DropBox failing to implement the 'Menu' interfaces on the non-existant '/MenuBar' DBUS path.
DBUS fans can explore `org.kde.StatusNotifierWatcher` with `d-feet` to find out more. Since the dropbox binary is responsible for supporting those interfaces, there is nothing to do but wait for the next update. BTW, all needed QT5.5 libs are included with the program. No need to download development packages.

I also found that only the GUI dialog seem to reliably keep the startup file from reinstalling. Once 'Start DropBox on system startup' was unchecked, it stayed that way.

Comment: The above workaround worked for me on all my machines. Thank you.

Comment: Here's a one-liner for this fix: `sed -i.bak '/#!\/bin\/sh/a export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=""' ~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd; dropbox stop && dropbox start`

Comment: I guess this could be applied in Xubuntu 16.04, too, but it uses systemd instead of upstart by default.

Comment: See [my answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/832942/21005). For my surprise, the init script worked in Xubuntu 16.04, too, even if it uses systemd instead of upstart.

Comment: I read somewhere that upstart would still be used for user mode services after systemd was rolled out, which would explain why the script still works.  The list of services is in  `/usr/share/upstart/sessions`

Comment: How can you start dropbox by the init script in terminal so that no logout is needed?

Comment: Use `initctl --user start dropbox` to restart the user mode upstart job as a child of the user `init` process.

Answer (score 2):

I run the same OS, Xubuntu 14.04 x64, and am seeing this icon which is unresponsive to clicks (no menu):

[image: Dropbox icon on Xfce4-Panel]

Release notes for [3.14.5](https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205672126-Release-Candidate-3-14-5) (which arrived as of 9 Feb 2016 and was installed on my machine) state that Dropbox has been updated to use Qt 5.5 on Linux.

Running the following gives the Qt version on my machine:

```
~$ qmake -v
QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.2.1 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

So, I [upgraded to Qt 5.5 using the instructions from here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/279421/how-can-i-install-qt-5-x-on-12-04-lts).

These are the steps I took:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:beineri/opt-qt551-trusty
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qt-latest qtcreator-latest
```

I then set the following in `~/.bashrc` and restarted the session:

```
export QT_SELECT=opt-qt55
```

I verified I have Qt 5.5 now installed:

```
~$ qmake -v
QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.5.1 in /opt/qt55/lib
```

Then, reinstall Dropbox and restart your session:

```
sudo apt-get remove dropbox
sudo apt-get install nautilus-dropbox
```

Unfortunately, this didn't work, and the tray icon appeared the same.

Then, I wondered if removing the Indicator Plugin from the Xfce4-panel would work.

1. Remove Indicator Plugin
2. `~? dropbox stop && dropbox start`

Then, suddenly, a wild dropbox icon appears in the Notification Panel!

[image: Dropbox icon appears]

It seems that the Dropbox icon likes residing in the Notification Panel, but not the Indicator Plugin.

But... I like the Indicator Plugin, as it gives me email alerts and volume level control. So, I re-added it to the panel. So far, so good.

But, after re-starting the session, I get this bullshit again:

[image: Dropbox icon on Xfce4-Panel]

So, now I'm stuck. I don't know how to make the Dropbox icon appear in the Notification Panel instead of the Indicator Panel, and I'm sure has hell not going to repeat these steps every time I log in!

Comment: As you said, "It seems that the Dropbox icon likes residing in the Notification Panel, but not the Indicator Plugin." I think you were in the right track, as kk78's workaround shows.

Comment: Removing the indicator plugin was key for me -- just running `dropbox start` with `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=""` was insufficient to get dropbox out of the indicator plugin.

Comment: @BSchlinker maybe dropbox was running already before you tried to launch it with `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=""`?

Answer (score 2):

This fixes it.

On the Dropbox menu go to Preferences. Deselect "Start Dropbox on system startup"

Go to Session and Startup > Application Autostart and add the following startup item:

```
bash -c 'export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="" && dropbox start -i'
```

Comment: Simpler: `env DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="" dropbox start -i`

Comment: @blujay or even `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS= dropbox start -i`. But some people report `dbus-launch dropbox start -i` works better.

Comment: @jarno Not everyone uses a Bash-style shell.  For example, I use Fish as my interactive shell, and variables are not set with the `name=value` syntax, so it's necessary to use `env`.  Using `env` works everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

(tested on xbuntu 17.04)

To restart dropbox with the correct tray icon: `dropbox stop && dbus-launch dropbox start`

Dropbox replaces the autostart file `~/.config/autostart/dropbox.desktop` on startup with `/usr/share/applications/dropbox.desktop`. To make the fix permanent, modify the latter:

```
sudo sed -i 's/Exec=dropbox start -i/Exec=dbus-launch dropbox start -i/' /usr/share/applications/dropbox.desktop
```

You may also want to modify the Main menu launcher:

```
sed 's/Exec=dropbox start -i/Exec=dbus-launch dropbox start -i/' ~/.local/share/applications/dropbox.desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer per se but given we're a sizeable enough community:
[HERE](https://www.dropbox.com/support/email/dropbox_app/submit)'s the direct link to the dropbox email customer support page. If we all ask them about this maybe they'll fix it themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Since my dropbox is a startup application search Dash for `Startup Application` then hit Edit on Dropobox entry and replace

old

> dropbox start -i

new

> env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity dropbox start -i

to engage issue :  alt-F2  then type in r  hit enter

This works for Ubuntu 18.10 and above