# Dropbox indicator not working properly

Tags: indicator, dropbox

The dropbox indicator is not working properly.  The third funny looking icon is dropbox.

[image: Dropbox indicator]

I can confirm that because this icon disappears after `dropbox stop`, and it appears again after `dropbox start` or `dropbox start -i`.

The indicator comes with an empty menu.  It's annoying and useless.  While dropbox is still working on the background.

I'm using Ubuntu 15.10 and Xfce desktop. `appindicator1` installed and have tried to reinstall dropbox.  The dropbox version is `3.14.7`, it seems `3.12.5` doesn't come with this problem.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/732967 has several solutions to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a recent bug with the last update. It is also affecting my install on ubuntu 14.04 lts after the last update file a report on
 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus-dropbox/+bug/1546176

Answer (score 1):

Same here using xubuntu 14.04.3

I found this entry in      `~/.cache/xfce4-indicator-plugin.log`
repeated every time I restarted Dropbox

```
DEBUG      Indicator-Application     Building new application entry: org.kde.StatusNotifierItem-2553-1  with icon:  at position 1
DEBUG      libindicator-plugin       Entry added for io=libapplication.so
WARNING    LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB          Getting layout failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownObject: No such object path '/MenuBar'
CRITICAL   LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB          dbusmenu_menuitem_send_about_to_show: assertion 'DBUSMENU_IS_MENUITEM(mi)' failed
```

The last line was repeated every time I clicked on the panel icon.

I only just now confirmed that my installation was updated on 2/16/16 without me knowing about it!

Comment: I see the same messages here and the `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=""` trick isn't working anymore.

`Aug 13 11:57:07 volvox org.gnome.panel.applet.IndicatorAppletCompleteFactory[2940]: (indicator-applet-complete:3612): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-CRITICAL **: dbusmenu_menuitem_send_about_to_show: assertion 'DBUSMENU_IS_MENUITEM(mi)' failed`
`Aug 13 11:57:09 volvox org.gnome.panel.applet.IndicatorAppletCompleteFactory[2940]: (indicator-applet-complete:3612): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-CRITICAL **: dbusmenu_menuitem_send_about_to_show: assertion 'DBUSMENU_IS_MENUITEM(mi)' failed`