# Dropbox problem in Indicator applet in Gnome classic

Tags: 16.04, indicator, dropbox, gnome-classic

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 and as I am more comfortable with Gnome classic, I have installed gnome-session-flashback and happily using that. It has some issues that can be tolerated. However, one thing that's really bothering me is that when I click at Dropbox icon in indicator applet I get a black dropdown that shows nothing. (Please see figure below.) Any suggestion how to solve this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem and this solved the issue for me :

`dropbox stop && DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="" dropbox start`

I found the answer at : [Dropbox icon is not working Xubuntu 14.04 LTS 64](https://askubuntu.com/questions/732967/dropbox-icon-is-not-working-xubuntu-14-04-lts-64)

**EDIT** : This solution seems working only for the active session. And this one works after a reboot too : https://askubuntu.com/a/737615/545036

Comment: I have the same issue, and it seems different from the one in Xubuntu 14.04. This solution doesn't work.

Comment: Does not work for me. The Dropbox icon does not appear at all then. Instead, this worked for me: http://askubuntu.com/a/821264

Comment: unfortunately neither solution works for me under Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I tried that one solution but it didn;t work.. so I tried another solution mention here https://askubuntu.com/a/795864/356010 and it finally works. I'm using xubuntu 16.0.4 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me ... above answers did not help

By default dropbox is launched on boot up so edit how it gets launched

```
DASH -> start ( click on Startup Applications)
```

edit the Dropbox entry with this `Command:`

```
env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity dropbox start -i
```

now the dropbox menu no longer appears blank ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I used the Zarete's proposed answer and it worked with Metacity desktop session. Also [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/737615/545036).

But classic Gnome panel need also to be moved from right to left if you can't see the (new) Dropbox icon in it. The Dropbox icon could be hiding on right side of the complete notification area

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+right click on the notification panel and select Move, then move the panel order with the hand

Answer (score 0):

If you are using gnome-flashback or another Unity desktop, the proper fix that will make the dropdown look be consistent with the rest of the desktop theme is found in a patch here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus-dropbox/+bug/1559249

If you installed nautilus-dropbox, just add this patch to the appropriate place in /usr/bin/dropbox and it did the trick for me!