# How to fix missing dropbox panel icon with a startup script?

Tags: scripts, xubuntu, startup, dropbox, xfce-panel

I use Xubuntu 16.10 and I want to run following command [(this is the code for fixing dropbox icon)](https://askubuntu.com/a/736205/496493) every time Linux session starts:

```
dropbox stop && env DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="" dropbox start -i
```

How can I do it?

I copied the code as a new command in **session and start up** -> **Application autostart** but it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi Woeitg, posted. Please mention if it works, will delete if not.

Comment: now it works. sorry I was very busy today. tnx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xubuntu Dropbox Icon Fail](http://askubuntu.com/questions/732816/xubuntu-dropbox-icon-fail)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Timing issue

I am pretty sure it is because of the timing. The command most likely runs before its target is "in the field".

Changing the command into:

```
/bin/bash -c "sleep 15 && dropbox stop && env DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="" dropbox start -i"
```

...will probably do the job.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. There is a question mark icon instead of dropbox icon without any pop up menu: http://i.imgur.com/UcU8y1y.png . If I run the command in terminal, then everything is fixed as expected

Comment: @Woeitg please try to increase the time to 45, if it works (I am pretty sure it should) , try to find the edge.

Comment: Jacob's code updated to new implementation:
/bin/bash -c "sleep 15 && dropbox stop && dbus-launch dropbox start"

Comment: I also having an issue in my xubuntu 16.04 lts ..so I run the above command /bin/bash -c "sleep 15 && dropbox stop && env  DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="" dropbox start -i" and it finally works. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This problem bugged me for a -long- time, but finally a fix that works for me with Xubuntu 16.04:

The normal menu launcher (which works fine) uses `~/.local/share/applications/dropbox.desktop`

which contains the line:

```
Exec=dbus-launch dropbox start -i
```

The startup launcher (which has the bug) uses `~/.config/autostart/dropbox.desktop`

which contains the line:

```
Exec=dropbox start -i
```

**The solution:**

Use the same command for session startup as the normal menu launcher.
Dead easy - but just one problem:

When the dropbox app runs, it overwrites `~/.config/autostart/dropbox.desktop` with the command that fails, which it copies from `/usr/share/applications/dropbox.desktop`. So we need to fix this file rather than the one in `~/.config/autostart/dropbox.desktop`

1. In a terminal window, run the command:

   `sudo mousepad /usr/share/applications/dropbox.desktop`

   (if you don't use Mousepad, substitute the command for your preferred text editor)
2. Enter your password when prompted
3. Replace the line:

   `Exec=dropbox start -i`

   with:

   `# Exec=dropbox start -i
   Exec=dbus-launch dropbox start -i`
4. Save the file and close Mousepad.
5. Ensure that Dropbox Preferences are set to start Dropbox on system startup.
6. Reboot to test.