# Dropbox AppIndicator Menu broken in gnome-flashback

Tags: indicator, dropbox, gnome-classic, system-tray

## The problem

[image: Broken Dropbox Menu as appindicator in gnome-flashback]

This is a broken Dropbox indicator in gnome-flashback on Ubuntu 16.04.1. (Dropbox version: x86_64-9.4.94)

[image: Working Dropbox Menu in Unity]

As it can be seen here, it works fine in Unity. But how can I get *that* in gnome-flashback (as appindicator)?

## The workaround

[image]

When I force Dropbox to present itself as old-fashioned systray icon<sup>1</sup> the menu gets usable.

## Open questions

- What convinces Dropbox to present the color icon in gnome-flashback when it runs as appindicator? As indicator it is black&white in Unity.
- Can I fool Dropbox to believe it runs under Unity? Can I force "appindicator mode"?
- Is there something wrong in the Dropbox code failing to decide properly between systray/appindicator? This colored icon looks like the result of half systray, half appindicator...

---

<sup>1</sup> You can force Dropbox into "systray mode" by running `dbus-launch dropbox start` or `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS= dropbox start` instead of starting it with a plain `dropbox start`.

Comment: Addition: If you have the same problem for Steam, some hints how to solve it are here: https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/4795  For me `sudo apt install libdbusmenu-gtk4:i386` helped to solve the steam icon issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Can I fool Dropbox to believe it runs under Unity? Can I force "appindicator mode"?**

Yes, you can! Experiments show that Dropbox (or related) looks for the environment variable `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP`, a freedesktop.org standard thing reflecting the name of the Desktop Environment in use. Set it to `Unity` and Dropbox turns sane. (I tried other sensible values, but the results were worse.)

There will be several ways to plant that variable on Dropbox. I chose to edit the command line interface script `/usr/bin/dropbox` from the `nautilus-dropbox` package to always overwrite this variable. Add this line after the imports. It will also work for "Start Dropbox on system startup":

```
os.environ['XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP'] = 'Unity'
```

Comment: Addition [edit not allowed after 5 min]: It worked but only for gnome-flashback [metacity] not for gnome-flashback [compiz] sessions!

Comment: Yeah. This one did the trick on metacity of Ubuntu 16.04. Thanks!