# Xubuntu 16.04 Dropbox Indicator

Tags: xubuntu, indicator, dropbox

[dropbox-indicator.gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klxYF.gif)

This is the problem that I have. I tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/732967/dropbox-icon-is-not-working-xubuntu-14-04-lts-64/737615#737615) but it doesn't work for me. I have no idea what to do next. I can't access the setting either.

dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-16.4.30/dropbox is running.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dropbox icon is not working Xubuntu 14.04 LTS 64](http://askubuntu.com/questions/732967/dropbox-icon-is-not-working-xubuntu-14-04-lts-64)

Comment: Try [another answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/739018/37165) under the linked question, which suggests to run `dropbox stop && dbus-launch dropbox start`. This reportedly works in Xubuntu as noted in comments and tested working in Xubuntu 14.04 on my side.

Answer (score 0):

If you right-click the sound indicator on the panel and select 'Remove' it will remove the 'Indicator Plugin'.

On reboot dropbox seems to detect that the plugin is missing and use another mechanism which works.

You do lose your sound indicator, but if you don't need sound or have volume-keys on your keyboard it is a good tradeoff

Perhaps someone knows another plugin that can be used to adjust speaker volume?