# How can Dropbox sync status be checked?

Tags: nautilus, dropbox

Previously, the sync status of files of the Dropbox directory was visible by small Dropbox status icons placed on the icons of Dropbox files and by asking the Dropbox executable (https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/9192). On Ubuntu 16.10, I can see no Dropbox status icons nor does the Dropbox executable seem to be returning sync information for specific files and directories. How can this be achieved?

I've got `dropbox_2.10.0_amd64.deb` and `nautilus-dropbox_2.10.0_all.deb` installed (https://linux.dropboxstatic.com/packages/ubuntu/).

Comment: Are you sure it is not fixed with this: http://askubuntu.com/a/736339/15811 ?

Comment: @Rinzwind Thanks for the suggestion. In this case it didn't work, but I managed to find a command that appears to be working now and I've added it as a solution to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you Dropbox is starting with the system?

1. On the terminal type:

   dropbox start

It should appear the Dropbox icon on the top right corner;

2. Click on the Dropbox icon and choose 'preferences';
3. On the 'General' tab, there is the option 'Start Dropbox on system startup'

Comment: That did solve for Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: what a joke !!! where we find this in ubuntu CLI

Answer (score 1):

Executing the following command has made the Dropbox sync icon emblems visible in Nautilus:

```
sudo echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=100000 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf; sudo sysctl -p
```