# Dropbox indicator icon is not supporting the icon theme at the top panel in Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, icons, xfce, dropbox

As the screenshot shows, the Dropbox icon at the top panel in Xubuntu does not work along with the rest of the icon set. I am using Faenza icon set in this screenshot. But I've tried with other icon themes as well (such as obsidian, papirus etc) with the same result. Dropbox is not supporting the icon set. As a result the icon looks out of place. How can I make the Dropbox indicator icon to support the current icon theme?

I am using Xubuntu 18.04. Apart from this, the Dropbox itself works fine.

[image: Dropbox icon does not support the current icon theme]

Comment: I'll add that it's not an xfce only issue, it happened to me on lxqt too, and I suspect it will happen on any DE. Maybe the problem is with the themes?

Comment: Not the theme. I've changed to the vanilla theme and the problem still exists.

Comment: What I mean is that probably no theme has an icon for it and so it just shows it's default icon no matter which theme is used, vanilla theme included. I may be wrong of course.

Comment: Well... Faenza has exclusive icons for different tasks of Dropbox. But somehow, Dropbox skips those icons on my settings.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem with vanilla GNOME on Ubuntu. I figured out running Dropbox with this command fixes it:

```
env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity dropbox start -i
```

Comment: Perhaps you could explain in more detail how you discovered this fix and how it works so the community can benefit further.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't really. I don't remember where I found it (probably a different thread like this), and all I know is  that it work for my set up.

Comment: Go to the given link and follow the answer given by darl. https://askubuntu.com/questions/732967/how-to-fix-non-working-dropbox-icon-on-xubuntu-14-04-lts-64