# Dropbox disappeared from my tray, but I need the preferences dialog!

Tags: dropbox, system-tray

I spent some time this morning trying to designate an ext4 partition as my Dropbox sync location, but Dropbox kept rejecting my ext4 partition. This related question: [Dropbox: ext4 isn't ext4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066045/dropbox-ext4-isnt-ext4) offered some suggestions but at some point the Dropbox icon disappeared from my system tray.

Dropbox is running -- I created a new text file and it syncs to another Dropbox instance promptly, but without the tray icon I can't open the preferences and if I cant open the preferences I can't designate a new sync location.

There are a lot of questions that seem related, but no so far none of the solutions work.

As suggested in [several](https://askubuntu.com/questions/720860/dropbox-disappearing-from-system-tray-after-unplugging-from-second-monitor) [answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/732967/how-to-fix-non-working-dropbox-icon-on-xubuntu-14-04-lts-64), I ran `dropbox stop && DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="" dropbox start` which doesn't seem to have made a difference -- still no system tray icon. It did return two warnings which seem relevant:

```
(dropbox:3946): libappindicator-WARNING **: 19:05:47.t941: Unable to get the session bus: The given address is empty
(dropbox:3946): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: 19:05:47.941: Unable to get session bus: The given address is empty
```

What can I do with this `libappindicator-WARNING`? Or is there a way to pull up the Dropbox preferences window without the system tray icon? I'm on 18.04, running Gnome. `dropbox status` reports that Dropbox is up to date.

Comment: What is your desktop environment (GNOME, KDE, MATE, Xfce)?

Comment: added it. Gnome.

Comment: Two wild guesses, 1) look for a config file to edit manually in a text editor (look in ~/config/...) or failing that try 2) test for additional command options by typing dropbox in terminal and double-tapping the Tab key to see if anything is suggested. Unlikely but this has saved me before when trying to discover random CLI options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wound up running Software Updater and restarting, which restored the system tray icon.

I'm slightly annoyed that that's what worked but I guess the moral of the story is:  check for software updates before you tear your hair out.